# Part of a chessboard - tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, chess

I'm a real beginner in using `tikz` and I would like to create something like this:

[image]

Is there a fancy/easy way to create something like this?

Comment: In case you need: http://www.ctan.org/search/?phrase=chess

Comment: @Sigur: I think it is misleading to point to chess related questions. Such patterns should be done directly with tikz.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I agree. I just commented because those chess package could be useful to OP. Soon or later he/she could wish to draw some chess movements.

Comment: @Sigur: I doubt that this intended for the game chess. The board isn't ragged like this and board have and white fields. People often say "chessboard" when they simply need some pattern with square.

Answer (score 9):

You can use a one liner

```
\documentclass[border={10}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}  

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach\x in{0,...,3}{\draw[style=help lines,shift={(\x,\x)}](0,0)grid[step=1](4,3);}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably I did ruin a one liner phrase by adding the complete code. Sorry for that.